# When I try to create a date object from another date format, the result date is changing it's value

Tags: javascript, date

When I try to create a date object from another date format, the result date is changing it's value. How to achieve this without changing the date value ?

```
new Date("Mon, 31 Oct 2016 00:00:00 GMT");
```

the result coming as Sun Oct 30 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), How can I get the Monday 31 date from the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting the **timezoneOffset** from the created date object should do the trick,
but be cautious while using it , as you should be sure that the date object was created from GMT not from some local time .

***And the below answer has been posted assuming the input date was in GMT***

```
var tempDate = new Date("Mon, 31 Oct 2016 00:00:00 GMT");
var tempTime = tempDate.getTime() + (tempDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
tempDate = new Date(tempTime);
console.log(tempDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't change the date, it just converts it to your local timezone. This is a bit of annoying behaviour and the only way I know to get around it is to set your system timezone to GMT. If you need to do date and time work, you might want to look at Moment.js - http://momentjs.com/